# Java Android - TabPager loads all Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, tabpage

i have 4 fragments, each of them loads and parses JSON, so that's why when I run the application, TabPager loads in the background all fragments.

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager Tab;
    TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                      actionBar = getActionBar();
                      actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);                    }
                });
        Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        //Enable Tabs on Action Bar
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){
      @Override
      public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
          FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }
      @Override
       public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
              Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
          }
      @Override
      public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
          FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }};
      //Add New Tab
      actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Page 1").setTabListener(tabListener));
      actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Page 2").setTabListener(tabListener));
      actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Page 3").setTabListener(tabListener));
      actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Page 4").setTabListener(tabListener));
    }
}
```

Because of this, a person loses a lot of internet traffic, I need to fix it. How can this be done?

Comment: Question isn't clear enough. Do you wan't not to reload fragment on tab switch?

Comment: m, when app started, viewpager loads all fragments in background, but  not only first (or selected).